# Return the choice of a combobox javafx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an app with 2 ComboBox and I would like to return the choice of the user into a variable. How should I do it ? 
Here is my controller class :

```
package ch.makery.adress;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HexaController implements Initializable {
       static JFrame fileDialog;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> hexa;
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        @FXML
        private TextField entree;

        @FXML
        private TextField excel;

        @FXML
        private TextField sortie;


        @FXML
        private void dar(ActionEvent event){
            FileDialog fd1=new FileDialog(fileDialog,"Choisissez un fichier d'entree",FileDialog.LOAD);
            fd1.setDirectory("C:\\");
            fd1.setVisible(true);
            String filename1=fd1.getFile();
            String Directory1=fd1.getDirectory();
            String path1=Directory1 + filename1;
            entree.setText(path1);
        }

        @FXML
        private void modele(ActionEvent event){
            JFrame parentFrame=new JFrame();
             FileDialog filechooser = new FileDialog (parentFrame, "Choisir un modèle Excel à copier",FileDialog.LOAD);
             filechooser.setDirectory("C:\\");
             filechooser.setVisible(true);
             String directory_copy = filechooser.getDirectory();
             String name_copy= filechooser.getFile();
             String path_copy = (directory_copy+name_copy);
             excel.setText(path_copy);
        }

        @FXML
        private void sortie (ActionEvent event){
            JFrame parentFrame2=new JFrame();
             FileDialog filechooser2 = new FileDialog (parentFrame2, "Choisir une destination d'enregistrement",FileDialog.SAVE);
             filechooser2.setDirectory("C:\\");
             filechooser2.setVisible(true);
             String directory_save = filechooser2.getDirectory();
             String name_save= filechooser2.getFile();
             String path_save = (directory_save+name_save+".xls");
             sortie.setText(path_save);
        }
        @FXML
        private void annuler (ActionEvent event){
            System.exit(0);
        }


        @FXML
        private ComboBox<Integer>methode;
        ObservableList<Integer>nombre = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



public HexaController(){

}

public void initialize(URL url,ResourceBundle rb){

    list.add(new String("OUI"));
    list.add(new String("NON"));
    hexa.setItems(list);
    nombre.add(new Integer(0));
    nombre.add(new Integer(1));
    nombre.add(new Integer(2));
    nombre.add(new Integer(3));
    nombre.add(new Integer(4));
    nombre.add(new Integer(5));
    methode.setItems(nombre);
}
}
```

I need to use that variable to change the way the app is going to work. And on the "methode" combobox I want a new window with a number of TextField. For exemple If the user choose 3 it will open a new window with 3 textField or (if it's possible just add 3 TestField below the combobox)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to the selected value of a ComboBox in JavaFX try this:

```
hexa.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

This returns the selected item. In your case it is an String as u declared it in your line `private ComboBox<String> hexa;`

I hope i understood it right now. With your second ComboBox "methode" you want to have options like "1","2","3" and so on ? There u can get the selected Item in the same way as we did it before:

```
methode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

Or if you want your program to immediately open a new window when a value is clicked on your "methode" ComboBox you have to add a `ValueChangedListener` to listen when the value is changed and then grab the selected item with the code above and open a new window with the information of the selected item.

For further research I recommend to take a look at this site from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm

Maybe there are some interesting additions for you.

I hope this helps you.

Edit:

Static problem

Try somtehing like this. This worked for me.

```
private ComboBox<String> hexa;
private Button changeBehavior;

changeBehavior.setOnAction.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            String userChoice = hexa.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
            // do something with that string
            }
        });
```

Methode combobox:

```
  private ComboBox<Integer>methode;

  methode.setOnAction((event) -> {
      int number = methode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
      paneYouWantToChange.getChildren().clear() // removes all displayed item

      /*Or if you want to replace somehting in your pane*/
      paneYouWantToChange.getChildren().set(indexOfItemToReplace, new TextField())

      /*Add new textfields*/
      paneYouWantToChange.getChildren().addAll(new TextField(), new TextField())
  });
```

Comment: Thanks it helps for the begining ! But What I want to do with my second combobox "methode" is for example the user select the choice 2 in the combobox the interface should change and add 2 Textfield. I don't know if I made myself  clear.

Comment: And I also have some issues because for exemple I want to create an event and I can't use : methode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() It tells me that methode has to be static but if it is static I have NullpointerExeption

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that.