# ComboBox getValue() and setValue() vs getSelectionModel.getSelectedItem() and select()

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

(Unfortunately) I've been learning JavaFx kind of on the go so my knowledge comes more from SO rather than some systematical learning. Therefore, I've been using `comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` and `...select()` as found in several posts here on SO and elsewhere. Today I somehow noticed that (expectablly) `ComboBox` also has the `getValue()` and `setValue()` methods, which are probably better for this purpose. Are there any differences or drawbacks to any of these approaches? I can imagine some when talking about editable ComboBoxes but I'm rather interested in non-editable ComboBoxes here.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html). Is there anything specifically you need to know that is not explained there?

Comment: Thanks for reacting quickly. I actually read this documentation page just before posting my question and quite understood it. It just doesn't seem to mention if there is any difference. So far I've been using comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() (like some other people in their answers here on SO e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32335084/3519572). Having noticed the comboBox.getValue() method, I would like to change all my existing code to use this instead. But before I do, I wanted to ask some more experienced programmer if there's actually any difference between these two.

Comment: It enumerates several differences, e.g. "Clearing the selection in the selection model does not null the value property - it remains the same as before."

Comment: Ok, you're right. I think I've been using ComboBox the wrong way so far. I guess I'll need to read it once more tomorrow morning and consider the influence of the change a bit deeper. Thank you.